# MS Teams calls drop after taking clients out of hold

Tags: microsoft-office-365, softphone, microsoft-teams

Good morning!

We're having an issue for around 2 weeks now and MS and provider support is sluggish at best.

We have a calling queue for our company in A. Whenever an agent puts a client on hold and has to resume the call, it immediately drops. This is obviously infuriating our agents and our clients at this point.

A few other employees also complain about calls dropping instantly or max. 2 seconds when the other side picks up, but that happens inconsistently.

We have not received any complaints about not being able to resume from other outposts of our company, only in A. Our Provider says he doesn't see anything in the logs, all calls are terminated with a *BYE* signal, as if someone hangs up.

In our logs we get *response code N/A.* We have no package loss or anything like that.

**What we have:**

- MS 365 Business Voice
- W10 clients
- Jabra Pro 9450 (or similar) headset for call agents
- Jabra Engage 75 for other employees

**What we tried:**

- Rebooting
- Reinstall Teams
- Switch Users
- Shut down duplicate Instances of Teams
- Update Jabra software
- Remove custom greeting
- Checked all policies, tinkered with them
- Deinstall any old UC software (MiVoice and xPhone)
- Take the old UC server completely offline
- Network / Firewall configurations (Open Ports, etc.)
- Use a fresh client machine
- Use a different network (LTE Hotspot)
- Skype for Business Analyzing tool (showed everything is suuuper
  great)
- etc.

A lot of the Tips we found on the Net are outdated by now, telling you to disable features that no longer exist etc.

Does anyone have a clue what this could be? Ever experienced something like this? We've been chasing ghosts for days now and we're growing tired. Any hint or clue in this matter could help.